# using fprintf in windows kernel device driver

Tags: c++, c, windows, file, driver

I need to make a dump of certain structure in a file in Windows driver. So for the file pointer, I used void pointer and use it in the place of file pointer in fprintf.

The source also build successfully without any compilation error. But when I load the driver, the value stored on that pointer is not printing.

How I should make use of fprintf in Windows driver.

Comment: Don't use the C I/O functions in device drivers, use the Windows API instead. The standard function from the CRT might have locking and other things happening that can disrupt or lock up or even crash your driver.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: You'd also want to avoid the Windows API inside the driver, as the moniker generally refers to the user-mode component. It is only for use from user-mode code. Only the kernel-mode APIs defined in the NT DDK (or WDK, as it is called lately) should be used.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using [DbgPrintEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543634(v=vs.85).aspx) inside your device driver.

printf won't be working for you in kernel mode.

DbgPrintEx prints to the kernel's DbgPrint buffer, which can be watched with a kernel debugger like WinDbg or Kd, or, if you want to watch it on the local system, [DebugView](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/debugview.aspx).

Most of the messages you print to this buffer are filtered out by default, so you want to adjust the filtering, as described in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff551519(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: As a side note, you'll (obviously) need a kernel debugger (Windbg ; Kd) or a tool like sysinternals `DebugView`to see the resulting output from a call to `DbgPrint[Ex]` function.